# Launch a service from within another service using handler

Tags: android, timer, handler

using my Broadcast receiver, I'm setting a shared preference (BT_Device_connected), whenever a Bluetooth device is connected.

now, the app i'm writing turns on Bluetooth automatically when you plug in the phone (yes, i know it's not recommended. focus! ;).

what i'm trying to do is wait 2 minutes after the phone has been plugged in, and check to see if during those two minutes the phone has connected to a Bluetooth Device (if BT_device_connected is true, it has, if false, it hasn't).

so, i'm trying to launch a timer/handler from within one service, and wait 2 minutes, and then   either launch a new service, or a method that will check if the device is connected.

and... i have to do all this in the Background, since none of this actually affects ui.

the glorious code i have, which doesn't work, is as follows:

```
public void onDeviceConnectTimer(){

TimerTask wait;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer t = new Timer();
wait = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(CheckIfDeviceConnectService.class.getName());
                            getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
                         Log.d("TIMER", "Timer set off");
                        }
               });
        }};
    t.schedule(wait, initializeDate()); 
 }
```

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `handler` like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable myRunnable=new Runnable()
{
public void run()
  { 
    //Start sevice here.

  }
};
```

Now start runnable by:

```
handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 120000);
```

This will start your service after 2 minutes.

Comment: however, as a newbie, i'm having trouble actually launching a service from inside the runnable - it seems to not like my context... I would LOVE an update to the code with a launch service example in it... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to start the `service` from a `BroadcastReceiver` or from another service?

Comment: I just ended up creating another method and running it, instead of launching another service...

Comment: So, what exactly are you looking for?